# cannot stop Thread Groups and start next Thread when I reached the EOF in jMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have Test Plan that contains Thread Group that is used CSV file. The point is that all data fron CSV file can be done much earlier than the duration for Thread Group would be over, so I try to use a condition to forcerly stop me Thread Group with this CSV file and starting next Thread Group under condition "if I reach EOF". But, for unknown for me reason I couldn't do it, the THread Group is not stopped.

What I've tried:

- set in CSV Data Set Config elements "Recycle on EOF" to false + "Stop thread on EOF" to false + "Sharing mode" to All thread
- set "If controller" with `${__jexl3("${documentIdFromCSV}" != "<EOF>",)}` condition (Thread Group has the next structure)

  - Thread Group

    - If Controller
    - HTTP request

      - CSV Data Set Config
- same with "While controller" wuith script `${__javaScript("${documentIdFromCSV}" != "<EOF>",)}`(Thread Group structura was the same as abovementioned)
- JSR223 Samples / PreProcessors / PostProcessors with script

```
def file = new File("somedoc.csv")

def numLines = file.readLines()

if (numLines == '' || numLines == null) {
    log.info("Reached end of CSV file. Stopping thread.")
    SampleResult.setStopThread(true)
}
```

Nothing from this worked and after jMeter reached the EOF -> thread is not stopped, it just print in jmeter.log file something like `INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stop Thread seen for thread <thread_name>, reason: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of file:somedoc.csv detected for CSV DataSet:CSV Data Set Config configured with stopThread:true, recycle:false` and continue to activate threads without any requests within this Thread Group.

I'll appreciate any help, thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're stopping the **thread** (single virtual user) and it sounds like you need to stop the **test**.

So the [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) call you're looking for is most probably:

```
SampleResult.setStopTest(true)
```

this way JMeter will "ask" all the threads to stop. If you want to forcesfully terminate the test - use the following command:

```
SampleResult.setStopTestNow(true)
```

Put the line of your choice into "Script" area of the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and put the JSR223 Sampler under the If Controller.

More information:

- [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: Hi! Thx for response. What I need - is to stop the current thread group if I reached the EOF and start the next thread group, not the whole test run. 

So, if I'm not mistaken I could use as in description:
 set in CSV Data Set Config elements "Recycle on EOF" to false + "Stop thread on EOF" to false + "Sharing mode" to All thread AND add your suggested script `SampleResult.setStopTestNow(true)` in JSR223 Sampler under the If Controller (and in If controller I should leave this condition `${__jexl3("${documentIdFromCSV}" != "<EOF>",)}` or not?